# Lie algebra of a Lie group literature

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm currently writing my thesis and want to use the concept of Lie-algebras. I explained everything with the definitions of a lie-algebra that I had of an old lecture. There the lie-algebra of a lie-group is defined as the tangent space at the identity element.
I understand that there is an isomorphism between this tangent-space and the set of left-invariant vector-fields but I do not want to make things more complicated and just state it like this.
The script does not have literature advice and in the standard differential geometry literature that I know the definition is different.

Can anyone advice me a citable document?

Comment: Daniel Bump, "Lie Groups" is an alright book.

Comment: @yoyo thanks for posting that comment;!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like "Differential Geometry and Lie Groups
A Computational Perspective" [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030460396).

See definition $18.6$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

"Can anyone advice me a cite-able document?"
I am unsure about what kind of  answer/document you want.

Like this one?
http://courses.theophys.kth.se/SI2320/luku4.pdf

at side $45$:

*Since the left (right) translation is bijective, a left (right) invariant vector field isuniquely determined by giving its value at a single point, at the identity, say.  Thus as a vector space, the space of left invariant vector fields can be identified as thetangent spaceTeGat the neutral elemente $\in G$.*

Comment: I had a bit problems with formatting symbols, I'm still a bit new but I'm getting better, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but in your source they also define the lie-algebra with vector-fields.

Comment: I'm looking for "the li-algebra of a lie-group $G$ is defined by $T_eG$"

Comment: Oh,  sorry I probably got you wrong; can you tell me what exactly you are looking for? Thanks for replying :)    EDIT: I read your updated comment.

Comment: Does it have other names? or can be defined and/or described differently?    I mean, can you provide a link that shows the definition (just so I can see it) Or maybe It's that you're asking for?